# Fitting 2 divs side by side in a 100% div

Tags: html, css

Looking to fit 2 horizontal divs in a 100% repsonsive div. So the 2 internal divs will resize when the screen shrinks/increases.

```
<div class="mydownloads">
<div class="warrantybook"><a href="http://www.example.com/link1"></a></div>
<div class="brochurebook"><a href="http://www.example.com/link2"></a></div>
</div>

.mydownloads {
width:100%;
}

.warrantybook {
padding:10px;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:45%;
}
.brochurebook {
padding:10px;
float:right;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:45%;
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with your current code? This will place the divs side by side with no issue. You just need to make sure to clear your floats when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the full div to 100% and the 2 internal divs to 50% and remove all padding, border and margin. I would recommend setting a "min-width" in css to ensure there is always a minimum, I've seen a lot of sites look goofy without having a minimum width on certain things.

```
<div class="mydownloads">
<div class="warrantybook"><a href="http://www.example.com/link1"></a></div>
<div class="brochurebook"><a href="http://www.example.com/link2"></a></div>
</div>
.mydownloads {
    width:100%;
}

.warrantybook {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
.brochurebook {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gn6jabb9/

Comment: Looks good, so no inline-blocks are needed. Will it auto adjust the height with no setting?

Comment: By adding `height:100%;` to the child divs and a height to the parent div it will scale height automatically. https://jsfiddle.net/gn6jabb9/2/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily enough with floats or inline-blocks, though the clean 'new' way is with Flexbox. Assuming you don't need support for IE < 10:

```
.mydownloads {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start; /* Change this to 'stretch' if you also want full height */
}

.warrantybook,
.brochurebook {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 50px;
}

.warrantybook {
    background:red;
}

.brochurebook {
    background:blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gn6jabb9/1/